# Как сконвертировать mssql в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть mssql база как я могу ее сконвертировать её в MySql?
Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать ?

Comment: Простейший вариант экспорт в SQL из MSSQL -> импорт из SQL в mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать sql или xml дамп базы

Comment: SQL Dump может содержать информацию, которую не поймет MySQL. Лучше через XML или XLS

Answer (score 0):

Пока в голову приходит только вариант с "Экспортом данных" через SQL Management Studio в Excel: `Правой кнопкой по БД, там Task -> Export Data...`
А после этого уже каким-нибудь phpMyAdmin - импорт этого Excel.

Вообще можно подключить, как DataSource в Windows - MySQL сервер, и тогда можно данные напрямую из MSSQL в MySQL перегнать. НО ТОЛЬКО ДАННЫЕ. Если в базе содержаться функции или процедуры, то с ними так просто не получится.